# How to define a conditional subset from another set?

Tags: notation

i want to define a subset from a set such that $$\\$$
X = n for: n < a and n > b

how can i write this in correct math notation?

$$X \subseteq n |n<a \wedge n > b$$

Comment: Is $n$ a set? In that case what does "$<$" mean?

Comment: You've not given enough information to recommend a "correct math notation".  What is the original set called (say $S$)?  Now what do you want to call the subset (say $X$)?  It seems you are using $n$ to mean both the original set and the parameter that determines the subset.  But what "Kind" of thing is $n$?  Is it a number?

Comment: I have a set of numbers, and I want to make a subset of the entries of that set, that fullfills the requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use words?

> $n$ is in $X$ when $b < n < a$  .

If you want symbols
$$
X = \{ n \in N \, | \, a < n < b \}
$$

The missing context is that there's a set $N$ of numbers.

Comment: sorry, I should have added more information.
n is a set of numbers
X should be a subset of that set, that fullfills the conditions

Comment: $$ \wedge $$ is the **And**-operator

Comment: I've edited my answer to deal with @MikaelWendt 's comment, and the your clarification (which should be part of the question, not a comment). If $n$ is a set then "$n < a$? makes no sense so I've assumed $n$ is a generic element of some given set $N$ you want a subset of.